# Numbers on matrix do not look good

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get what's on this picture:

[image]

> The problem is that when I add numbers the **Q** matrix, they don't look the same as in the original picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,
                positioning}
\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                      nodes in empty cells,
                      nodes={minimum height=3ex, minimum width=1em,
                             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                             draw, very thin, fill=yellow},
                      column sep=0pt,
                      row sep=0pt,
                      inner sep=0.5\pgflinewidth, outer sep=1pt,
                      draw, thick},
 empty node/.style = {draw,fill=none},
every label/.append style = {font=\large, text=teal}
    }
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell{%
\iftikz@lib@matrix@empty%
\node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,empty node]{};\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
\matrix (m1) [mymatrix,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left: items},
              label=below:$R$,
              label=above:users]
{
1   &   & 3 &   &   & 5 &   &   & 5 &   & 4 &   \\
    &   & 5 & 4 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
2   & 4 &   & 1 & 2 &   & 3 &   & 4 & 3 & 5 &   \\
    & 2 & 4 &   & 5 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 &   \\
    &   & 4 & 3 & 4 & 2 &   &   &   &   & 2 & 5 \\
1   &   & 3 &   & 3 &   &   & 2 &   &   & 4 &   \\
};
\node (approx) [right=of m1] {$\approx$};
\matrix (m2) [mymatrix=none, right=1em of approx,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left: items},
              label=below:$Q$,
              label=above:factors]
{
    0.1& -0.4  & -0.2 \\
    -0.5& 0.6 & 0.5 \\
    -0.2& 0.3 &0.5  \\
    1.1& 2.1 & 0.3 \\
    -0.7&2.1  & -2 \\
    -1& 0.7 & 0.3 \\
};
\node (times) [right=of m2] {$\times$};
\matrix (m3) [mymatrix=none, right=of times,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=north]right: factors},
              label=below:$P^T$,
              label=above:users]
{
 1.1&-2  & 0.3 & 0.5 &-2  &  -0.5 & 0.8 & -0.4 & 0.3 & 1.4 & 2.4 &  -0.9\\
 -0.8& 0.7 & 0.5 & 1.4 &0.3  & -1 & 1.4 & 2.9 & 0.7 & -  1.2 & & 1.3\\
 2.1& -0.4 & 0.6 & 1.7 & 2.4 & .9 & -0.3 & 0.4 &  0.8 &   0.7 & -0.6&0.1 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have problems with the size, also:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the widths of the nodes were hardcoded. If you want to fix this with this code, you need to increase these widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,
                positioning}
\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                      nodes in empty cells,
                      nodes={minimum height=3ex, minimum width=1em,
                             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                             draw, very thin, fill=yellow},
                      column sep=0pt,
                      row sep=0pt,
                      inner sep=0.5\pgflinewidth, outer sep=1pt,
                      draw, thick},
 empty node/.style = {draw,fill=none},
every label/.append style = {font=\large, text=teal}
    }
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell{%
\iftikz@lib@matrix@empty%
\node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,empty node]{};\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
\matrix (m1) [mymatrix,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left: items},
              label=below:$R$,
              label=above:users]
{
1   &   & 3 &   &   & 5 &   &   & 5 &   & 4 &   \\
    &   & 5 & 4 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
2   & 4 &   & 1 & 2 &   & 3 &   & 4 & 3 & 5 &   \\
    & 2 & 4 &   & 5 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 &   \\
    &   & 4 & 3 & 4 & 2 &   &   &   &   & 2 & 5 \\
1   &   & 3 &   & 3 &   &   & 2 &   &   & 4 &   \\
};
\node (approx) [right=of m1] {$\approx$};
\matrix (m2) [mymatrix=none, right=1em of approx,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left: items},
              label=below:$Q$,
              label=above:factors,
              nodes={minimum width=2em}]
{
    0.1& -0.4  & -0.2 \\
    -0.5& 0.6 & 0.5 \\
    -0.2& 0.3 &0.5  \\
    1.1& 2.1 & 0.3 \\
    -0.7&2.1  & -2 \\
    -1& 0.7 & 0.3 \\
};
\node (times) [right=of m2] {$\times$};
\matrix (m3) [mymatrix=none, right=of times,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=north]right: factors},
              label=below:$P^T$,
              label=above:users]
{
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want to fill the cells in the second matrix yellow, add `nodes={fill=yellow}` only to the first matrix

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,
                positioning}
\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style = {matrix of math nodes,
                      nodes in empty cells,
                      nodes={minimum height=3ex, minimum width=1em,
                             inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                             draw, very thin,scale=0.9,transform shape},
                      column sep=0pt,
                      row sep=0pt,
                      inner sep=0.5\pgflinewidth, outer sep=1pt,
                      draw, thick},
 empty node/.style = {draw,fill=none},
every label/.append style = {font=\large, text=teal}
    }
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell{%
\iftikz@lib@matrix@empty%
\node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,empty node]{};\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
\matrix (m1) [mymatrix,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left: items},
              label=below:$R$,
              label=above:users,
              nodes={fill=yellow}]
{
1   &   & 3 &   &   & 5 &   &   & 5 &   & 4 &   \\
    &   & 5 & 4 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
2   & 4 &   & 1 & 2 &   & 3 &   & 4 & 3 & 5 &   \\
    & 2 & 4 &   & 5 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 2 &   \\
    &   & 4 & 3 & 4 & 2 &   &   &   &   & 2 & 5 \\
1   &   & 3 &   & 3 &   &   & 2 &   &   & 4 &   \\
};
\node (approx) [right=of m1] {$\approx$};
\matrix (m2) [mymatrix=none, right=0.1em of approx,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=south east,xshift=-0.7em]left: items},
              label=below:$Q$,
              label=above:factors,
              nodes={minimum width=2.4em}]
{
    0.1& -0.4  & -0.2 \\
    -0.5& 0.6 & 0.5 \\
    -0.2& 0.3 &0.5  \\
    1.1& 2.1 & 0.3 \\
    -0.7&2.1  & -2 \\
    -1& 0.7 & 0.3 \\
};
\node (times) [right=of m2] {$\times$};
\matrix (m3) [mymatrix=none, right=of times,
              label={[rotate=90, anchor=north]right: factors},
              label=below:$P^T$,
              label=above:users]
{
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

instead.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marmot! I've updated the OP. How can you make matrices Q and P^T look exactly as in the original picture? Meaning, with white background?

Comment: @naveganTeX This is written in the lower part of the answer. You need to add `nodes={fill=none}` or add `fill=yellow` only to the first matrix.

Comment: Done! It works! Now I have a new problem, it does not fit the pages' size. Check the edited post

Comment: @naveganTeX I fixed this by moving the label to where it is in your screen shot.

Comment: I cannot fix it. I will ask a new question.

Comment: The hyphens should be proper minus signs.

Comment: @egreg For that one only needs to replace `matrix of nodes` by `matrix of math nodes`.